import mysql.connector not working MacOS 15.1.1 - Python 3
I have a python3 file:
from flask import Flask, request
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="*host*",
    user="*user*",
    password="*password*",
    database="*database*"
)

cursor = db.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "<h1>404</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p>", 404

@app.route('/<date>/<temperature>', methods=['POST'])
def index(date, temperature):
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO temperature VALUES ('{date}', {temperature})")
        db.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Failed to insert data into MySQL table: {error}")
        db.rollback()
    return "Data inserted successfully"


@app.route('/addtemperature/', methods=['POST'])
def addtemperature(date, temperature):
    data = request.json()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000 )

and when I run it using:
python3 app.py

I get a error saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/Desktop/Python3/Raspberry Pi Pico/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

I am using anaconda and I have already installed mysql-connector-python.
I have also tried uninstalling then reinstalling.
I am using MacOS 15.1.1 (Sequoia)

How did you install mysql-connector-python?
